# Resource ID is not returning correct value

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view, android-resources, android-drawable

I am having difficulty displaying the images in a ListView.

The output that I want should contain the different images for different list items.
However what I am getting is this:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see that the icons that are being displayed are same (booking).
What I could figure out until now is that the method `itemImagesViews.setImageResource(itemsImages.getResourceId(position, R.drawable.booking))` from the `ItemAdapter.java` file is not returning the expected value.

Here is the repo:

https://github.com/amar0891/Aroma-Holiday

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the code in ItemAdapter.java. But basically all you need is do this, if you want to see booking icon:

```
itemImagesViews.setImageResource(R.drawable.booking);
```

Note: I don't know what code setup you have with getResourceId() and maybe that is the main problem.

Another good solution, recommended by Google, I think is:

```
Resources resources = getResources();
itemImagesViews. setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.myfirstimage));
```

Note: itemImagesViews is your ImageView. setImageDrawable method is supposed to be more efficent with large images.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your code

```
     if (convertView == null){
        you are setting the image only when the convert view is null but not 
      always the convertView is null 
     }
```

So what you should do is

```
   View view=convertView
  if (view == null){

        view= activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_adapter_view, null);

        }
 TextView itemDetailsViews = (TextView) view .findViewById(R.id.item_details);

        itemDetailsViews.setText(itemDetails[position]);

        TextView itemsDescriptionsViews = (TextView) view .findViewById(R.id.item_description);

        itemsDescriptionsViews.setText(itemDescriptions[position]);

        ImageView itemImagesViews = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_image);

        itemImagesViews.setImageResource(itemsImages.getResourceId(position, R.drawable.booking));
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName().toString(), "" + itemsImages.getResourceId(position, R.drawable.booking));
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName().toString(), "" + R.drawable.booking);
```

you have to assign your set your imageviews and textviews after the if not inside the if

Comment: try now. I edited the code.I did not check one convertView to view.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your files and the reason `getResourceId` is always returning the default value is because the items in your array are not resources, they're just strings.You should add the references to your resources in your array. Try this instead:

```
  <array name="items_images">
    <item>@drawable/plane</item>
     ....     
</array>
```

Comment: I didn't get it. Did it really work or are you still looking for another answer? :P